# how to resolve the error "Bad request .Combination of host and port requires TLS."

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to consume a  rest end point but i am getting the below error

> Bad request .Combination of host and port requires TLS.

This is the code i have written

```
GET_URL ="https:/path/data"
    URL obj = new URL(GET_URL);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode)
```

Below code is from other team who is exposing the rest end point.
Rest End point has SSL enabled.when i checked the code it says

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getData() {
        
        return "Hello World";
    }

server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    client-auth: need
    key-store: {keystore-path}
    key-store-password: {keystore-password}
    key-alias: alias-name
    key-store-type: JKS
```

How can i solve the error? Can you provide the steps

Comment: you need to present the client certificate to the server. If you have no idea what im talking about, you should google how TLS works, and how to install certificates in java.